# Regular expression matches too often

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I have a string which contains certain class names + method calls. I'd like to extract these but the regex I wrote to do this returns more matches than intended.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$someInput = "Lorem ipsum  dolor sit CLASS3.aMethod.anotherMethod amet, consetetur sadipscing CLASS1.bMethod elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod";

@matches = ($someInput =~ /((CLASS1|CLASS2|CLASS3)(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+){1,})/g);
foreach my $match (@matches) {
    print $match . "\n";
}
```

Instead of one match in the form "CLASS.methodOne.methodTwo..." it also matches the class name and the methods separately. Please have a look at the example result:

```
CLASS3.aMethod.anotherMethod
CLASS3
.anotherMethod
CLASS1.bMethod
CLASS1
.bMethod
```

What I actually want:

```
CLASS3.aMethod.anotherMethod
CLASS1.bMethod
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with this. A short explanation would also be great :) Thanks!

Comment: Remove all useless capturing groups and use non-capturing groups when needed. Display only the group you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression

```
((CLASS1|CLASS2|CLASS3)(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+){1,}))
```

defines 3 capture groups, each delineated by a balanced pair or parentheses:

```
1: ((CLASS1|CLASS2|CLASS3)(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+){1,})
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

2: ((CLASS1|CLASS2|CLASS3)(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+){1,})
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

3: ((CLASS1|CLASS2|CLASS3)(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+){1,})
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and so when one expression is successfully matched against this expression, the result will be 3 matches.

Use the `(?:...)` syntax to keep an expression together as a logical unit in a regular expression but to designate it as a *non-capturing* group. This expression will only return one match on success:

```
((?:CLASS1|CLASS2|CLASS3)(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+){1,})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution! I'm not using regular expressions that often and didn't even know about non-capturing groups... Great, learned something new today ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have 3 matching groups:

```
$1 = ((CLASS1|CLASS2|CLASS3)(\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+){1,})
$2 = (CLASS1|CLASS2|CLASS3)
$3 = (\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+){1,}
```

and all these groups ($1, $2, $3) you put in @matches.